# solr search with all documents being retrieved

Tags: solr, nutch

I used nutch 1.4 to crawl web sites, and indexed data to solr 3.5. this was successful. I used Luke to check the index data and found 1678 documents were fetched. but when I entered a query string (just a few key words) in the solr interface for search, all 1678 documents were retrieved. this is weird since most retrieved web pages did not contain these key words at all.

Any idea for this problem?

Thank you.

Thunder

Comment: It could be anything. Can you add some details? Your 'schema.xml' for example and the query you're trying. Thanks

Comment: what I crawled is a medical library web site. it contains mostly medical terms and terminologies. For example I entered query string 'Clinical Allegy & Clinical Immunology', solr returns all 1678 docs. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, I used 'schema.xml' directly copied from Nutch 1.4 which is located under nutch_home/runtime/local/conf.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, people usually have "missing document" type problem when they search with Solr. You have the opposite problem :)

You should be able to see why that's happening immediately after you open your index with Luke.
The default search field with Nutch's schema is Content, so when you enter only search term into Solr that's the field that is going to be searched. Examine its contents using Luke.

You are, of course, aware of these valuable resources:
http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/09/10/refresh-using-nutch-with-solr/
http://groups.drupal.org/lucene-nutch-and-solr 
http://www.mail-archive.com/nutch-commits@lucene.apache.org/msg02227.html